# cCall multiple cmd files from one custom script extension

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-resource-manager

I am trying to write one PowerShell script that contains calling mutiple cmd files. This ps file will be invoked by custom script extension in ARM template.

here is my trial:

```
Configuration IIS
{
 Node ("localhost")
  {
    #Install the IIS Role
    WindowsFeature IIS
    {
      Ensure = “Present”
      Name = “Web-Server”
    }

#Install ASP.NET 4.5
WindowsFeature ASP
{
  Ensure = “Present”
  Name = “Web-Asp-Net45”
}

 WindowsFeature WebServerManagementConsole
{
    Name = "Web-Mgmt-Console"
    Ensure = "Present"one 
}

 Invoke-Item File 'srvConfigure1.cmd'  
 Invoke-Item File 'srvConfigure2.cmd'
 Invoke-Item File 'installfiles.ps1'
}
}
```

How can I do that in a sequential way (one after one)?

Comment: I would start by spelling Invoke-Item correctly.

Comment: @milbrandt unless you have the poster's code to look at I'm not sure how you can justify that edit. Since the exact same typo was made on three lines in a row that sounds like the original code has the typo and it was copy and pasted.

Comment: I rolled the edit back. Changing typos in code presented in a question is not the right way to go. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286905/why-is-an-edit-that-fixes-typos-in-code-inappropriate

Comment: Next, the powershell Invoke-Item cmdlet does not have a File parameter and even if it did it would bespecified by -File not File. Did you mean -Path? Is this code that you have actually tried?